# one namespace cannot find class in the other namespace

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, reference, namespaces, partial-classes

i'm new to c# .Net. in my solution, two namespaces cannot see each other.

I have project A which has partial class c1 and some methods in it.
Project B with a different namespace also has a partial class c1, some methods with same name of which in project A and some other methods.

I have added the reference in project A that reference to project B, have the using namespace B included in project A classes.

But still in A, i can't use what's in class c1 from B, i can only see the method of class c1 from A itself. i want to use methods of c1 from both projects in A.

Can anybody help me with this please? i'm using .Net framework 4

Comment: so i made the two projects the same namespaces by changing the properties and the namespace part in their classes. they are still two different projects only with the same namespace. would that work? i just want to use some method of c1 from B in project A, where that method of c1 is also defined in A with some overlaps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is presumably a full class in the other namespace, but only defined as a partial class in a particular file. You can't, as @tzerb mentions, have two of the same partial class in two different namespaces - by virtue of the fact that the namespaces are different, the class names themselves (fully qualified) are different.

If all you need is to use the methods from class B in class A (and perhaps override them), you can either use inheritance:

```
class A: B
{
    // override methods from B
    // or call base.<method> when needed
}
```

Or containment:

```
class A
{
    private B _b;

    // construct and use _b methods directly
}
```

Use inheritance if `A` *is a* `B`, use containment otherwise.

Comment: It's still different projects. For project A to reference something from project B, it needs to *compile* B and include it in A. Once you've compiled a class, you can no longer use it in a `partial` definition - you can now contain or inherit it, as per my answer.

Comment: Thanks yamen, the things is A and B are two projects with many classes and the same namespace.

In project A:

namespace Example1{
  public partial class c1{
    public void getsomething(){return result1;}
  }
}

In project B:

namespace Example1{
  public partial class c1{
    public void getsomethingElse(){return result2;}
  }
}

I want to be able to call getsomething() and getsomethingElse() in projectA, but i cannot see getsomethingElse() now since its in a different project...

Comment: Create object B: `var b = new B()`, then call it: `b.getSomethingElse()` in `class A`.

Comment: "Once you've compiled a class, you can no longer use it in a partial definition - you can now contain or inherit it" --Okay, thanks, i think i get it a little bit now..:)

Comment: but A and B are actually the same namespace,and same class name, only different project names...i cannot create instance of B in A since they have the same names.. i just want to call getSomethingElse() in project A.. is that possible ?

Comment: No. You can't have two partial class definitions in different projects. Change the namespaces, or change the class names, then use one of the methods outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

The partial classes have to share a namespace.  The two partial classes called c1 are totally different classes.